# TypeScript on Visual Studio 2012 Express

Tags: visual-studio-2012, typescript

I've been having trouble getting TypeScript for Visual Studio 2012 to work.  Does anyone know if it will only install on the full edition of VS2012? (I have VS 2012 **Express** for Web and VS 2012 **Express** for Desktop).

I've tried all the suggestions I could find on this site, and still no luck.  Both VS and TypeScript install correctly, but I can't see TypeScript projects or new items anywhere in VS 2012 Express for Web.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **TypeScript** project likes to hide directly in **Visual C#** or **Visual Basic** node of projects templates tree of *VS 2012 Express for Web*. Just click on one of those, scroll to very bottom and check if it's there:

[image: TypeScript project under Visual C# node]

Comment: Ah, found it under C#.  Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

More specifically, TypeScript doesn't have its own project type currently, so there are effectively just templates leveraging other project types currently (such as C#).

Even more difficult to find is the ASP.NET MVC 3 TypeScript template.  For this choose "Visual C# / Web / ASP.NET MVC 3 Web Application" template, then when you click OK you get the option for the TypeScript template (see shot below).

Also, as there is no native project system for TypeScript, its build actions are just Exec tasks within the C# project files currently.  i.e. in the csproj you will see an action such as:

```
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <Exec Command="&quot;$(PROGRAMFILES)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\0.8.0.0\tsc&quot; @(TypeScriptCompile ->'&quot;%(fullpath)&quot;', ' ')" />
  </Target>
```

[image]